# An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, odata

I have created `odata` service and pack up into the Web installer. That package is working properly once I installed on my computer but I can't use it on other computers when I tried to run on different computers, it comes up with the following errors:

Any help would be really appreciated.

> An error has occurred. 
>   An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration.
>   See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator =
>   ConfigDataContext (ReflectionActivator), Services =
>   [Deswik.MDM.Spatial.MDMPoints.DataContexts.Interface.IConfigDataContext],
>   Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None,
>   Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while
>   invoking the constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Deswik.MDM.SqlCommandBuilder.Interface.ISqlCommandBuilder,
>   System.String)' on type 'ConfigDataContext'. ---> The ConnectionString
>   property has not been initialized. (See inner exception for details.)
>   (See inner exception for 'enter code here'details.)
>   
>   Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
>    at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable'1
>   parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable'1 parameters) at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable'1 parameters) at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable'1 parameters, Object& instance)
>   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable'1 parameters) at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable'1 parameters) at
>   Deswik.MDM.Spatial.MDMPoints.Controllers.MDMPointsController.Get(ODataQueryOptions'1
>   queryOptions) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary'2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
>     An error has
>   occurred.  An exception was thrown while
>   invoking the constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Deswik.MDM.SqlCommandBuilder.Interface.ISqlCommandBuilder,
>   System.String)' on type 'ConfigDataContext'. ---> The ConnectionString
>   property has not been initialized. (See inner exception for details.)
>   
>   Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
>    at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable'1 parameters) at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable'1
>   parameters)   An error has
>   occurred.  The ConnectionString property
>   has not been initialized. 
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection
>   outerConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource'1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource'1
>   retry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource'1
>   retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   Deswik.MDM.Spatial.MDMPoints.DataContexts.ConfigDataContext..ctor(ISqlCommandBuilder
>   sqlCommandBuilder, String connectionString) at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()

Answer (score 5):

The exception tells you what is wrong:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

When you're creating your connection you have to define the `ConnectionString` beforehand.

Comment: Did you initialize it? As in `ConnectionString cString = new ConnectionString { _define parameters here_}`

Comment: thank you guys I find the issue it was .net frame 4.6 . the other guy didn't install 4.6. as the application require 4.6 to run.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I had a hard time finding the actual error message in all of the other stuff.